# Using auto_mkindex for TCL scripts

Tags: tcl

I am working with some legacy TCL scripts that use `auto_mkindex`. To understand how it works, I have set up a minimal example but have not been able to correctly source the files. My starting files are

```sh
.
├── main.tcl
└── util
    └── hello.tcl
```

The file contents are:

```
# main.tcl
puts [hello]

# hello.tcl
proc hello {} {
    return "Hello World"
}
```

In `./util` I ran `auto_mkindex .` from `tclsh` which generated a `tclIndex` file in `./util` with the line

```
set auto_index(hello) [list source [file join $dir hello.tcl]]
```

Then when using `tclsh` from the root of the project I append `auto_path` with the path to the `util` directory. However, when I call `hello` I get an error saying `Invalid command name "hello"`. Clearly I'm missing something. What is it?

Comment: I think we need more detail about your current directory, and the command used to manipulate auto_path. This works for me: `env TCLLIBPATH="$TCLLIBPATH ./util" tclsh main.tcl`

Comment: @glennjackman thanks for pointing me in the right direction. It was as simple as having the wrong path appended to `auto_path`.

Answer (score 0):

For a `tclIndex` file to work, it *must* be in a directory on the `auto_path`.

Check with:

```
foreach dir $auto_path {
    puts "$dir -> [glob -nocomplain -directory $dir tclIndex]"
}
```

It's very easy to put the wrong path on. However, it's often easiest to make your main script add paths relative to itself:

```
lappend auto_path [file join [file dirname [file normalize [info script]]]] util]
```